# ¿Cómo lograr actualizar los registros de una sola vez?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, model-view-controller

estoy intentando actualizar el registro de algunos atributos de mi aplicación, tengo un formulario en donde ingreso la `:cantidad_bidon` y `:kg_bidon`, esto realiza una operación de multiplicación, guardando en un nuevo campo el resultado, `:total_kg`...

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "item_compras", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "compra_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "calibre_id"
    t.integer  "kg_bidon"
    t.float    "precio_kg"
    t.float    "sub_total"
    t.integer  "total_for_kg",   default: 0
    t.float    "total_compra",   default: 0.0
    t.integer  "cantidad_bidon"
    t.integer  "total_bidones",  default: 0
    t.integer  "total_kg"
  end
```

**Model Compra.rb**

```
    class Compra < ActiveRecord::Base
    include AASM #Maquina de estado

    has_many :item_compras, :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_compras, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**Model ItemCompra.rb**

```
class ItemCompra < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :compra
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :calibre
end
```

compras_controller.rb (Método new, create y update)

```
# GET /compras/new
  def new
    @compra = Compra.new
    2.times { @compra.item_compras.build }
    @products = Product.all
    @calibres = Calibre.all
  end

  # GET /compras/1/edit
  def edit
    @bidons = Bidon.all.map{ |b| [b.nombre, b.id] }
    @proveedors = Proveedor.all.map { |p| [ p.nombre, p.id]  }
  end

  # POST /compras
  # POST /compras.json
  def create
   @compra = Compra.new(compra_params)
   actualiza_total_bidones!(obtiene_total(:cantidad_bidon))
    actualiza_items!
    #@compra.proveedor_id = params[:proveedor_id]
    respond_to do |format|
      if @compra.save
        format.html { redirect_to @compra, notice: 'La compra ha sido creada exitosamente.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @compra }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @compra.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /compras/1
  # PATCH/PUT /compras/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      actualiza_total_bidones!(obtiene_total(:cantidad_bidon))
      actualiza_items!
      #@compra.bidon_id = params[:full_name]
      #@compra.proveedor_id = params[:proveedor_id]
      if @compra.update(compra_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @compra, notice: 'Compra actualizada exitosamente.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @compra }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @compra.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Métodos private**

```
def obtiene_total(atributo)
  items = params[:compra][:item_compras_attributes]
  items.values.map { |item| item[atributo].to_i }.reduce(:+)
end

def actualiza_total_bidones!(total_bidones)
  @compra.item_compras.each { |item| item.total_bidones = total_bidones }
end


def actualiza_items!
  @compra.item_compras.each do |item| 
    total = [item.cantidad_bidon, item.kg_bidon].reduce :*
    item.total_kg = total
  end 
end


def set_compra
  @compra = Compra.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def compra_params
  params.require(:compra).permit(:proveedor_id, :calibradas, 
    :calibre, :tipo, :bidon_id, :product_id, 
    :descripcion, :cantidad_comprada, 
    :conductor_id, :created_at, :gastos, :kilos, 
    :state, :numero_camion, :mic, :factura, 
    item_compras_attributes: [
      :id, :cantidad_bidon, :product_id,
      :calibre_id, :kg_bidon, :precio_kg, :total_kg,
      :total_for_kg, :sub_total, :total_compra, :total_bidones, :_destroy 
      ])
  #item_compras_attributes representa los detalles que 
end
```

El problema que tengo, es que cuando ingreso una nueva `:cantidad_bidon` no se actualiza el `:total_kg`, tengo que hacer clic nuevamente en editar y guardar para que realice la operación (osea editar el ítem dos veces). ¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que lo sucede es que primero se calcula el total con el método `actualiza_items!` pero, en la siguiente línea, si se incluye `:total_kg` en los parámetros, `@compra.update(compra_params)`, se sobreescribe el valor que se acaba de calcular.

En todo caso, lo mas recomendable es que estos cálculos se hagan en el modelo. Si el atributo `total_kg` siempre será calculado con la multiplicación de `cantidad_bidon * kg_bidon`, podrías omitirlo completamente en el formulario y el controlador y calcularlo en el modelo automáticamente antes de guardar los datos.

```
class ItemCompra < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :compra
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :calibre

  before_save :calcula_total_kg

  private

  def calcula_total_kg
    self.total_kg = cantidad_bidon.to_i * kg_bidon.to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: Podrías evitar la conversión a entero (i.e. `to_i`) ya que ambos atributos (`cantidad_bidon` y `kg_bidon `) son números.

Comment: @Gerry, Tienes toda la razón. Sin embargo, existe la posibilidad de que en algún momento el campo tenga un valor nulo. Prefiero no arriesgar a que aparezca una excepción.

Comment: Tienes razón, probablemente lo mejor sería agregar una validación en el modelo para tratar los nulos; pero creo que eso pertenece a otra pregunta.

Comment: Claro, para ello evito los valores nulos, utilizo un valor default 0 para los totales y `accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_compras, 
 reject_if: RejectDeeplyNested.blank?` para evitar guardar campos en blanco. (Gem: reject_deeply_nested)